# differential area

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, applications

I'm just trying to refresh my calculus a bit, I'm stuck on a question and I'd love some insight.

A square measures 0.9cm on each side when drawn with a pencil. When traced over with a marker, it measures 0.95cm on each side. Use the differential of area, $dA$, to estimate the increase in area of the square.

What I would do is this:

$$s_p = 0.9cm$$
$$s_m = 0.95cm$$
$$ds = s_m- s_p = 0.05cm$$

$$dA = s_m * ds = .95cm * .05cm = 0.475cm^2$$

Comment: is $(0.95)^2$ minus $(0.9)^2$?

Comment: That's what I would naturally think too, but apparently not

Comment: @janmarqz You're not using the differential, and you're not finding an approximation. You're just working out the answer.

Comment: in this case the differential approximation is too rough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A square of side length $x$ (units) has area $A(x)=x^2$. The derivative of $A$ with respect to the side length is $$A'(x)={dA\over dx}=2x.$$

But, the derivative gives a rate of change. If the side length changes by an amount $\Delta x$, starting from a point $x=x_0$, then the area changes by an amount $\Delta A$.  The relationship between these changes and the derivative is
$$
{dA\over dx}\biggl|_{x=x_0}\approx {\Delta A\over \Delta x}.
$$

This follows from the (limit) definition of derivative.

In your problem $x$ changes from $x=x_0=.9$ to $x=.95$, so $\Delta x=.05$. Then using the above, the corresponding change in area is
$$\Delta A\approx {dA\over dx}\biggl|_{x=.9} \cdot\,\Delta x=2(.9)\cdot(.05)=.09\,{\text {cm}}^2$$

Answer (score 4):

The formula for the area of a square is $A = \ell^2$, where $\ell$ is the length of each side. Hence
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}A}{\mathrm{d}\ell} = 2\ell$$
This can also be written as $\mathrm{d}A = 2\ell\,\mathrm{d}\ell$. Here $\mathrm{d}A$ is the infinitesimal difference in the area and $\mathrm{d}\ell$ is the infinitesimal difference in the length of each side. You have $\ell = 0.9$ and $\mathrm{d}\ell = 0.05$. Hence

$$\mathrm{d}A = 2\times 0.9 \times 0.05 = 0.09$$